# Enviar email luego de insert con php, html y mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Muy buenos días, necesito una ayudita con lo siguiente:

Tengo un formulario en HTML:

```
<form name="formulario" method="POST" action="enviar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Orden nro.: 
<select name="nro_pedido">                        
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<br>

Nro. de pedido:
    <input name="po" id="po" type="text"/>

<br>

Cliente:
    <select name="client">                        
             <option value="CLIENTE 1">CLIENTE 1</option>
</select>

<br>

Lote: <select name="nro_lote">
     <option value="EJEMPLO 1">EJEMPLO 1</option>

</select>

Factura: <input name="nro_factu" id="nro_factu" type="text"/>

<br>

<input type="submit" value="ENVIAR"/>

</form>
```

Luego en el archivo enviar.php recibo las variables y las inserto en la base de datos:

```
<?php
require("conexion.php");
$conexion=conectar();

$nro_pedido=$_POST['nro_pedido'];
$po=$_POST['po'];
$client=$_POST['client'];
$nro_lote=$_POST['nro_lote'];
$nro_factu=$_POST['nro_factu'];

$sql="insert into embarques(nro_pedido,po,client,nro_lote,nro_factu)
values('$nro_pedido','$po','$client','$nro_lote','$nro_factu')";


$ok1=mysqli_query($query,$conexion);
/* PARA EJECUTAR SENTENCIAS EN LA BASE DE DATOS
UTILIZAMOS LA FUNCIÓN mysqli_query(sentencia,conexion)*/

$ok=mysqli_query($sql,$conexion);

if ($ok)
    {
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Correcto!');
        window.location='formulario.php';</script>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Error')
    window.location='formulario.php';</script>";
    }
?>
```

Cuando presiono el botón ENVIAR los datos del formulario van al archivo -enviar.php- allí solo recibo las variables y luego hago un insert en la tabla de la base de datos, ahora como puedo hacer para que al momento de insertar los datos luego se genere un archivo pdf con esos mismos datos registrados y se envié a un correo en especifico por medio de los lenguajes que estoy usando:

PHP, HTML, MYSQL

Esto lo estoy haciendo de manera local y estoy usando xampp y phpmyadmin.

Comment: Hola @estrada Tu pregunta se puede considerar "demasiado amplia", recuerda realizar las preguntas en base a [ask], se más especifico y agrega información de lo que has tratado para lograr generar el pdf, de esta forma te aseguro podrás obtener la ayuda requerida en el sitio, saludos.

Comment: Entendido, actualmente ya genero mi pdf con una libreria que se llama html2pdf_v4.01, el problema es que no se como podria enviarlo directamente desde mi sistema hacia un correo electronico especifico, de todas formas muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de insertar los datos puedes usar un paquete para generar un PDF, si es algo simple, pudes usar DomPDF (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf), lo instalas usando composer:

```
composer require dompdf/dompdf
```

En caso de que no estes usando composer, como puedo ver en el código que pegas, puedes bajar el último release (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases) y pegarlo en el directorio, luego le haces un require:

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
```

Te sugiero leer la documentación para poder generar el archivo PDF que requieres pero los pasos son sencillos:

```
$html =
  '<html><body>'.
  '<p>Aquí va el html del PDF con la información que insertaste en la base de datos</p>'.
  '<p>Puedes usar las variables que quieras: '.$nro_pedido.'</p>'.
  '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('Brochure.pdf', $output);
```

Para enviar el email, te sugiero usar PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), para enviar el email los pasos son similares al dompdf, también, sugiero revisar la documentación pero para algo sencillo con esto basta (No olvides el require o la instalación via composer):

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->SetFrom('tu@dominio.com', 'Tu Nombre');
$email->Subject   = 'Asunto del mensaje';
$email->Body      = $bodytext; //Aqui va el cuerpo del mensaje
$email->AddAddress( 'destinatario@dominio.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'Brochure.pdf'; //Tomando en cuenta el ejemplo anterior

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NombreDelArchivo.pdf' ); //Puede ser otro nombre

return $email->Send(); //Puedes omitir el return si quieres seguir ejecutando cosas
```

Comment: Buenas tardes liga, esa respuesta esta excelente, ya tengo todo listo solo tengo la siguiente duda, yo configure el mercury mail del xampp y ya me funciona perfecto, ahora como tendria que hacer para cuando presione el boton guardar y en el archivo de enviar.php que debo poner para que despues de insertar el registro luego envie el correo mediante la funcion mail(); o como podria hacerlo. muchas gracias.

Comment: @estrada Hola, es como puse ahi en la respuesta, usa PHPMailer, creas el objeto, le das los parámetros y al final: 
`$email->Send();`. Si deseas usarl la funcion mail() es un poco mas complicado ya que tienes que setear las cabeceras del archivo dentro del cuerpo del mensaje. Esa es ya otra pregunta.

Comment: hola, entendido muchas gracias por la ayuda, te estare avisando si funciono. saludos.